# How to enter values between brackets and print out these values in JAVA

Tags: java, printing

I am making a program where a person can select a dish from a menu and can choose how many of that dish they want to order. I am using the following code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] starterList = {"Gazpacho with shrimps", "Carpaccio of veal    ", "Mushroom salad with nuts (v)"};

    System.out.println("Please choose what dishes you want to order");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("-- STARTERS --");

    for (int i = 0; i < starterList.length; i++){
        System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + starterList[i] + "\t" + "[ ]");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Choose how many you want of each:");
```

The idea is that behind every dish the user can fill in the amount they want to order between the [ ], after they filled in the amounts I should be able to print a overview what the order exactly consists of. This is where I get stuck. So I was wondering a) Is it even possible to enter values between the brackets? and b) How can I do it?

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Java doesn't really have much in the way of console support, when it comes to things like colors and character placement, you'd need to look for something like [Curses support](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=java+curses) to get any real decent support.  If you want to keep it simple, I'd simply use a `>` character and `print` to place the cursor at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

The console input does not allow this but you can try the following code

```
\\code starts
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Order {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] starterList = {"Gazpacho with shrimps", "Carpaccio of veal    ", "Mushroom salad with nuts (v)"};
    int[] quantity = new int[starterList.length];

    System.out.println("Please choose what dishes you want to order");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("-- STARTERS --");

    for (int i = 0; i < starterList.length; i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + starterList[i] + "\t" + "[ ]");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Choose how many you want of each:");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 if you do not want to order the dish:");

    for (int i = 0; i < starterList.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((i + 1) + ". " + starterList[i] + "\t");
        quantity[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your final order is:");
    int index=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < starterList.length; i++) {
        if (quantity[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println((index++) + ". " + starterList[i] + "\t" + "[ " + quantity[i] + " ]");
        }
    }

}
```

}
\code ends

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Unf8.png)

This should have an effect like this

Please choose what dishes you want to order

-- STARTERS --
1. Gazpacho with shrimps    [ ]
2. Carpaccio of veal        [ ]
3. Mushroom salad with nuts (v) [ ]

Choose how many you want of each:
Enter 0 if you do not want to order the dish:
1. Gazpacho with shrimps    2
2. Carpaccio of veal        0
3. Mushroom salad with nuts (v) 3

Your final order is:
1. Gazpacho with shrimps    [ 2 ]
2. Mushroom salad with nuts (v) [ 3 ]

here the order for 2nd item is 0 so it is not in the list of selected items.

Comment: Thanks! This perfect for what I want. Cheers mate